# Appending and removing code elements within Kivy language on button click

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have written a Kivy GUI that consists of various buttons and nested layouts. I want to be able to, on a click of a button, append a section of code n number of times within one of these layouts, specifically the scroll layout. Since I have am very new to Kivy and since I cannot seem to find a tutorial on this matter, I am presenting it here.

Here is the Python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Interface(Widget):
    pass

class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return Interface()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().run()
```

And the total Kivy code:

```
<Interface>:
    GridLayout:
        padding:0
        size: root.width, root.height
        cols:1
        #Top buttons
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.07
            padding:0
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:"Add Phase"
        #Chart areas
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_y:False
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.minimum_width
                GridLayout:
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: self.minimum_width
                    cols:20



                    #Phase template
                    GridLayout:
                        width: 200
                        size_hint_x: None
                        cols:1
                        TextInput:
                            size_hint: 1, 0.06
                            halign: 'center'
                            hint_text:"Phase"
                        TextInput:
                            size_hint: 1, 0.06
                            halign: 'center'
                            hint_text:"Step"
                        Button:
                            size_hint:1, 0.07
                            text:"Add Step"
                        GridLayout:
                            cols:20

                            #Step template
                            GridLayout:
                                width: 100
                                size_hint_x: None
                                cols:1
                                TextInput:
                                    size_hint: 1, 0.06
                                    halign: 'center'
                                    hint_text:"Var1"
                                TextInput:
                                    size_hint: 1, 0.06
                                    halign: 'center'
                                    hint_text:"Var2"
                                Button:
                                    background_normal: ''
                                    background_color: 0.28,0.59,0.72,1
                                    text:"Test"
                                Button:
                                    size_hint:1, 0.07
                                    text:"Delete"


                        Button:
                            background_color: 0.8,0,0,1
                            size_hint:1, 0.07
                            text:"Delete"
```

You will see in the Kivy code that these is a commented secion called `#Phase template`. Basically on pressing the button `Add Phase`, this entire section and its children elements should be appended in the immediate parent `GridLayout`.

Here you can press the Add Phase button:
[image: Here you can press the Add Phase button:]

Which will result in this:

[image: Which will result in this]

And then finally, pressing the `Delete` button should remove that specific appended section of code.

Again, no idea how to approach this from the Kivy language, which seems a bit rigid to work with. But I am sure what I want to do can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is to create a `Phase` class, and add a `kv` rule for building instances of `Phase`. Then, in `kv`, you can use `Factory.Phase()` to create new instances.

Modify your `kv` as:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<Interface>:
    GridLayout:
        padding:0
        size: root.width, root.height
        cols:1
        #Top buttons
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.07
            padding:0
            cols:1
            Button:
                text:"Add Phase"
                on_release: grid.add_widget(Factory.Phase())  # this adds another Phase
        #Chart areas
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_y:False
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.minimum_width
                GridLayout:
                    id: grid  # added id to identify where to add new Phase instances
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: self.minimum_width
                    cols:20

                    # initial Phase instance
                    Phase:

#Phase template
<Phase@GridLayout>:
    width: 200
    size_hint_x: None
    cols:1
    TextInput:
        size_hint: 1, 0.06
        halign: 'center'
        hint_text:"Phase"
    TextInput:
        size_hint: 1, 0.06
        halign: 'center'
        hint_text:"Step"
    Button:
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Add Step"
    GridLayout:
        cols:20

        #Step template
        GridLayout:
            width: 100
            size_hint_x: None
            cols:1
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, 0.06
                halign: 'center'
                hint_text:"Var1"
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, 0.06
                halign: 'center'
                hint_text:"Var2"
            Button:
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: 0.28,0.59,0.72,1
                text:"Test"
            Button:
                size_hint:1, 0.07
                text:"Delete"


    Button:
        background_color: 0.8,0,0,1
        size_hint:1, 0.07
        text:"Delete"
        on_release: root.parent.remove_widget(root)  # delete this Phase
```

Key points are the `<Phase@GridLayout>` rule, the new `grid` `id`, and the use of `Factory` in the `Add Phase` Button.